# Location Manager Displays default location even before GPS permissions are given

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location, locationmanager

[image: The app runs and displays the address in the logs even before the permissions for GPS is given.]

Here is my code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Setting up the Location Manager.
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    //Showing user location on the map as a blue dot.
    self.theMap.showsUserLocation = true

    //Setting the delegate for the map view.
    self.theMap.delegate = self
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations    locations: [CLLocation]) {

    //Getting the last recorded location.
    let location = locations.last
    let ceter = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:   (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)

    //Setting the region of the map.
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: ceter, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01))

    //Assigning the region to the map.
    self.theMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    //Stop updating the location.
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}


func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    //Getting the center coordinate of the screen.
    let thecenter = mapView.centerCoordinate

    //Storing latitude & longitude in seperate variables.
    let centerLat = thecenter.latitude
    let centerlon = thecenter.longitude

    //Converting CLLocationCoordinate2D to CLLocation.
    let movedMap: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: centerLat, longitude: centerlon)

    //Performing Reverse GeoCoding to retrieve address from Coordinates.
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(movedMap) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        //Checking for error.
        if(error != nil) {
            print(error)
        }else{

            //Taking the first coordinates among the lot & storing in variable 'p'.
            if let p = placemarks?.last {

                //Unwrapping Optional Strings.
                let roadno = p.subThoroughfare ?? ""

                //Checking if subThoroughfare exists.
                if(p.subThoroughfare != nil) {

                    //Unwrapping Optional Strings.
                    let thoroughfare = p.thoroughfare ?? ""
                    let subLocality = p.subLocality ?? ""
                    let locality = p.locality ?? ""
                    let administrativeArea = p.administrativeArea ?? ""
                    let postalCode = p.postalCode ?? ""
                    let country = p.country ?? ""

                    let address = " \(roadno) \r \(thoroughfare) \r \(subLocality) \r \(locality) \(administrativeArea) \(postalCode) \r \(country)"
                    print(address)

                   //Assigning the address to the address label on the map.
                   self.addressLabel.text = " \(roadno) \r \(thoroughfare) \r \(subLocality) \r \(locality) \(administrativeArea) \(postalCode) \r \(country)"

                }else{

                    //Unwrapping Optional Strings.
                    let thoroughfare = p.thoroughfare ?? ""
                    let subLocality = p.subLocality ?? ""
                    let locality = p.locality ?? ""
                    let administrativeArea = p.administrativeArea ?? ""
                    let postalCode = p.postalCode ?? ""
                    let country = p.country ?? ""

                    let address = " \(roadno) \r \(thoroughfare) \r \(subLocality) \r \(locality) \(administrativeArea) \(postalCode) \r \(country)"

                    print(address)
                    //Assigning the address to the address label on the map.
                    self.addressLabel.text = " \(thoroughfare) \r \(subLocality) \r \(locality) \(administrativeArea) \(postalCode) \r \(country)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure my error is the `regionDidChangeAnimated()` function, but I am not able to understand why it is reverse geocoding coordinates even before the GPS permissions are given.

*Edited

This is a new error message i get occasionally when i run the project.

Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.

[Here is the screen shot for the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvCE6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i kinda found a solution to the problem i was facing. I don't know if this is the right solution but doing this made the error go away and the map works fine.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(100, 80)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span)
    self.theMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)


    //Setting up the Location Manager.
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    //Showing user location on the map as a blue dot.
    self.theMap.showsUserLocation = true

    //Setting the delegate for the map view.
    self.theMap.delegate = self

}
```

So what i did here was basically initialise the map to 0 Latitude & 0 Longitude and set the region in the viewDidLoad() and the error went away. If by any chance this is not the right the solution let me know what the exact solution to this problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I think a big part of your problem is you're starting location updates and showing the current position in your map view *before* making sure that:

1. Location Services are enabled for the device
2. Your app has permission to use them

This is why you're getting that MapKit message.

Make sure that both requirements are fulfilled *before* using Location Services with `CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()` and `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()`.

As a reminder (I forget this one often), make sure you have the relevant usage description key in your **Info.plist**, one of either `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... I tried the 2 points you mentioned but for some reason i still get the same error and i have given both 'NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription' and 'NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription' description key in the Info.plist